# int vs int[] difference - autoboxing inside generics?

Tags: java, generics, autoboxing

See this piece of code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Temp{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<int[]> list1 = new ArrayList<int[]>(); //WORKS!
        List<double[]> list2 = new ArrayList<double[]>(); //WORKS!
        //List<double> list3 = new ArrayList<double>(); //DOES NOT WORK
        //List<int> list4 = new ArrayList<int>(); //DOES NOT WORK
    }
}
```

AFAIK, java generics does not support primitive types, then how is `int[]` is compiling? How is autoboxing possible here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`int[]` and `double[]` are object types which extend `Object` They are not primitives.

You cannot auto box with arrays. Only between primitives and their wrappers.

Answer (score 1):

You can to use only reference types (extends from Object) as generic therefore is not compiling with int and double.

Answer (score 1):

> AFAIK, java generics does not support primitive types, then how is int[] is compiling? How is autoboxing possible here?

Firstly, `int[]` and `double[]` are not primitive types.  They are reference types.

Secondly, there is no autoboxing going on here.  Autoboxing is when a primitive *value* is converted to the corresponding wrapper type *value*:

- There is no use of the wrapper type values here.
- Indeed, there are no *values* involved at all.  (`int[]` is a type not a value.)
- There is not even any type-level conversion going on here.

All there is is a compile-time type check that `int[]` is a subtype of `Object`.

And an attempted compile-time check that `int` is a subtype of `Object` ... that fails, and gives you a compilation error.

If you want a list of integers or doubles, you have to *explicitly* use the wrapper classes as the type parameter; e.g. `List<Integer>` or `List<Double>`.

Answer (score 0):

they are objects.
you can always use Integer or Double.
if you want to use int you should use Trove
http://trove.starlight-systems.com/